# Dependent columns using hansontable plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, handsontable

I am using jQuery [handsontable plugin](http://handsontable.com/) and I am wondering if there's any way to use "dependent" columns.

This is, when I change one column, the other would get updated depending on the previous column value.

One of my columns is call `location`, and the auto-complete shows a list of possible locations. (city + postal code + country)
That's correct, however, in my Database I am only storing an `id` for each location. Therefor I need a hidden column to store it (which I've already created) but I need it to get updated when the user change the `location` column using the auto-complete.

Is that possible somehow? I didn't find anything either in the documentation or at internet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have done exactly this for the same reasons as you

using the afterChange event...

```
afterChange: function (changes, source) { AfterChange(changes, source); }
```

... you can change values of other cells ...

```
function AfterChange(Changes, Source) {
    if (Source === 'loadData') {
        return; //don't do anything on load
    }
    var rowIndex = 0, columnID = 1, oldTextVal = 2, newTextVal = 3, ntv = '', nv = '';
    $(Changes).each(function () {
        if (this[columnID] === 'RegionID') {
            //Make sure nothing else happens when these columns are set through below, to avoid circular references
        }
        else if (this[columnID] === 'RegionName') {
            ntv = this[newTextVal];
            //I have a dropdown used for filtering which has the id as value where I get the id from
            nv = $('#RegionsFilterDropdown option').filter(function () { return $(this).text() === ntv; }).val();
            $container.handsontable('setDataAtCell', this[rowIndex], 12, nv);
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this helps...